# When did Dukhat first have contact with the Vorlons?

Tags: babylon-5

Dukhat was a great warrior and political leader to the Minbari people. He was [Delenn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delenn)'s mentor and friend. Part of his story is told in the TV movie, *[Babylon 5: In the Beginning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylon_5:_In_the_Beginning)*.

Wikipedia says [Dukhat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dukhat) had secret [Vorlon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorlon) advisors when Vorlons had not openly contacted the Minbari for a long time.

When did Dukhat first have contact with Vorlons?

I'm looking for answers from any episode, TV movie, or novel that mentions Dukhat's interaction with Vorlons. Please provide quotes from original sources with your answers.

Comment: While Dukath was respected from all the castes, I'm pretty sure he wasn't a "warrior". Besides that, I don't think there's any earlier "source" than "In the Beginning".

Comment: I remember that Valen had two Vorlons beside him when he presented B4 to the Minbari of 2159 (Earth calendar).  I don't remember anything which said that Dukhat had secret Vorlon advisors, whether the other Minbari knew of Vorlons or not.  Looks like it's time to review the Lurker's Guide.

Comment: @Mario The wikipedia article on Dukhat says *"even though Dukhat belonged to the **Warrior Caste** and Delenn to the Religious Caste"*. So we know he was a warrior. And since he was also one of their greatest leaders - second only to Valen - and that the Minbari warrior caste prized leaders who were adept at combat, it's not much to say he was a great warrior.

Comment: @can-ned_food Dukhat had two Vorlons with him on his spaceship just before the Earth-Minbari war. The Vorlons remained on the spaceship even after his death so they could advise Delenn.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only signs of contact in the show, you have already marked from *In The Beginning*.  There is no other tie-in material that concentrates on Dukhat's life, or this period.

Given that one special prequel movie is all we can draw from, **the only signs point to the Vorlons making contact just before the Earth-Minbari War.**

In the prequel movie *In the Beginning*, one of the scenes is of Delenn questioning a series of workers who are bringing alternate atmospheric equipment aboard the Grey Council ship.  This naturally begs the question, what is aboard that could require such equipment.  She is halted in her questioning by Dukhat, who only admits that there is a secret being kept.  This would have to coincide roughly with when the Vorlons came on board.

We cannot say with any certainty how long they were in contact with Dukhat before that.  Given that their... "physical" appearance ... would likely have been required to be convincing, I believe it's safe to say they had only recently made contact.  Bringing their atmosphere aboard suggests creating a permanent space for them, making them comfortable, so recent wouldn't have been that same day or hour.  Of course, on that same voyage, Dukhat died, so how much and how long they were actually able to advise him is an open question.

Comment: You know if a B-5 novel was printed tomorrow and declared a canon story, it could render this answer invalid. :-)